# How can I delete html tags from a file using sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, html

I have a file that is mixed with both normal text I need and html-tags. I know that with REGEX it is possible to recognize html tags and with sed one can swap those for an empty string, but I do not know how to apply it concretely.

Comment: `sed` is not good tool to remove html tags.

Comment: would it be possible to provide some samples? Are you looking to extract information from an XML file or cleanup some XML content within another file? Your choice of tool depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Down that path lies madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your HTML tags are confined to a single line, the following will work:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Comment: What will happen with `<tag attribute="legal use of >" foo=bar>`? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attribute-value

Comment: This will not handle comments correctly. Example: `<!-- > -->`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are not insisting on `sed`, the best thing to do this would be `lynx`.

`lynx --dump <filename>.html`

This will output the content of the html file in the format the html code was intending to display. The only condition is that the filename should have a `.html` or `.htm` extension.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend the use of either of the programs named `html2text` ([1](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text)) ([2](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/)) instead.  Parsing HTML is much harder than it looks.