# Delete html tags using sed/grep/awk

Tags: sed, grep

If we have the following, how can we delete all the tags?

```
Study eases concerns about taking antidepressants during pregnancy and autism risk <a href="https://t.co/Cs0mdeYEBo" rel="nofollow noopener" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU" ><span class="tco-ellipsis"></span><span class="invisible">http://</span><span class="js-display-url">cbsn.ws/2oTosqU</span><span class="invisible"></span><span class="tco-ellipsis"><span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span></span></a><a href="https://t.co/rs5813GdLG" class="twitter-timeline-link u-hidden" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >pic.twitter.com/rs5813GdLG</a>
```

The result after using the command should look like this:

```
Study eases concerns about taking antidepressants during pregnancy and autism risk
```

After using the following:

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

or

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g'
```

I get:

```
Study eases concerns about taking antidepressants during pregnancy and autism risk http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU&nbsp;pic.twitter.com/rs5813GdLG
```

Which is not exactly what I want. I need to do this using only either sed, awk,grep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete html tags from a file using sed ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185126/how-to-delete-html-tags-from-a-file-using-sed)

Comment: @TimKennedy that's not a duplicate. The OP is using precisely what the accepted answer there is suggesting and it fails on this input file. That's because their file is wrong, of course, but still.

Comment: HTML is _not_ a regular language, so attempting to parse it with regular expressions is the path to madness.

Comment: What you want is to remove the tags (which that sed does), and some of the text contained within some tags. Here you seem to want to remove `<a>some url</a>`, but you probably don't want to remove `<p>some text</p>`. You need to figure out which ones exactly you want to remove, and that would probably be much easier with an actual HTML parses library

Comment: You might be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4957508)

Comment: You're actually asking a question that can not have a good answer because of the way HTML is designed.  No matter how you proceed, there will **always** be cases that give you bad results.

Answer (score 1):

The command is working perfectly, your file is malformed. You can see this using `grep --color=yes <[^>]*>' file` or, by adding a newline after every `>`:

```
$ sed -e 's/>/>\n/g' file 
Study eases concerns about taking antidepressants during pregnancy and autism risk <a href="https://t.co/Cs0mdeYEBo" rel="nofollow noopener" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://cbsn.ws/2oTosqU" >
<span class="tco-ellipsis">
</span>
<span class="invisible">
http://</span>
<span class="js-display-url">
cbsn.ws/2oTosqU</span>
<span class="invisible">
</span>
<span class="tco-ellipsis">
<span class="invisible">
&nbsp;</span>
</span>
</a>
<a href="https://t.co/rs5813GdLG" class="twitter-timeline-link u-hidden" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >
pic.twitter.com/rs5813GdLG</a>
```

Note that the `http://</span>`, `cbsn.ws/2oTosqU`, `&nbsp;` and `pic.twitter.com/rs5813GdLG` are not inside html tags so they are left as is, quite correctly.

So, what you want isn't to remove the html tags, you want to remove the html tags *and some other stuff* but I have no idea how to know what you want and what you don't.